# Telegram at Startup?

Tags: startup, system-tray, minimize, telegram

I've installed the latest Telegram App (v 0.8.32) On my Ubuntu 14.04.
I want Telegram to run minimized at startup in Tray and show me new messages but I can't because In the app settings there isn't any option for that.
Help me How Can i do it....

Answer (score 44):

You should add a startup item to your startup application list, as mentioned by Mladen B.

The command is:

```
/opt/telegram/Telegram
```

Or, if you've installed Telegram via the software center or `snap`:

```
telegram-desktop
```

To start hidden:

```
/opt/telegram/Telegram -startintray
```

There is [a -now closed- bug](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/407) in Telegram using Unity: a sequence of "Open Telegram --> Minimize to tray --> Open Telegram" will show the window.

Comment: Mentioned bug is pretty annoying!

Answer (score 12):

You can add it to the list of startup applications, by going to Dash and start typing "startup". The "Startup Applications" icon should show up.

[image: startup]

Click on it and when it starts, click on the "Add" button to add your app to the list of applications which will start automatically each time you log in.
Also you can start it minimized by adding **-startintray** commandline option:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but how do we find out the "command" name?

Comment: Try looking in: ~/.config/autostart

Comment: Or in console, type: `which Telegram` and that should give you a full path to your Telegram binary.

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu 22.04) this is a command in StartApp Applications Preferences: /snap/bin/telegram-desktop

Answer (score 2):

Sadly none of them are work from the prevoius solutions.

What I did:

1. Created a bash script file with (You have to add the proper path of your Telegram executable. Relative path **didn't work**!):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /home/spyff/.telegram/Telegram &

   while true
   do
       xdotool windowminimize `xdotool search --onlyvisible --classname Telegram`
       if [ $? -eq 0 ]
       then
           break
       fi
       sleep 0.1
   done
   ```
2. Saved somewhere as `TelegramStarter.sh`
3. Added that script to the Ubuntu's **Startup Applications**

This start Telegram and if its actually started, minimize it immediately. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.3 with Telegram 1.1.23.

Answer (score 0):

You could use crontab, and enter this in the terminal:

```
  crontab -e telegram
  crontab restart
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: why was this voted down?